# How to add a favicon to a website built with the Publish static site generator?

Tags: swift, publish, static-site, static-site-generation

It looks like [the Publish static site generator](https://github.com/johnsundell/publish) usually picks up static assets from the `Resources` directory when I run the generator. I've added a `favicon.ico` file to this directory, but it isn't copied to the default `Output` directory. There is [a `Favicon` type](https://github.com/JohnSundell/Publish/blob/ef3cd95bc4b4307c516b7538c6c2dfcc943fc7a8/Sources/Publish/API/Favicon.swift) available with a corresponding `favicon` property on [the `Website` protocol](https://github.com/JohnSundell/Publish/blob/7a17e9eb8d5eda114cd0b1e8e4a317054df03952/Sources/Publish/API/Website.swift), but it's unclear how it should be set, and whether that would automatically copy the file to the `Output` directory.

What's the best way to get the `favicon.ico` file copied as a resource? Does this need a separate plugin, or how can it be achieved with the `Website` protocol API?

Answer (score 2):

Place the favicon in the `Resources` folder. The Website protocol has a favicon property

```
public protocol Website {
  ...
  /// The website's favicon, if any.
  var favicon: Favicon? { get }
  ...
}
```

Use that in your site which conforms to Website. You can refer to `Favicon` type in Publish for more info.

```
struct MySite: Website {
  ...
  var favicon: Favicon? { .init(path: Path("images/favicon.ico"), type: "image/x-icon")}
  ...
}
```

Comment: How do I add icons in multiple formats to support both `.ico` and `.svg` as described here? https://css-tricks.com/svg-favicons-and-all-the-fun-things-we-can-do-with-them/

Comment: @MaxDesiatov  If I understand correctly, you are asking for two favicon `link` tags. The first one referring to a `.svg`, and the second one referring to `.ico` which will act as a fallback. This requires implementing your own head method. How I would do this is, in your custom theme, add extension to Node like
`private extension Node where Context == HTML.DocumentContext`
Under which copy the implementation of the existing head. In it's return statement, just before where it unwraps the default favicon, add a `.element` named `link` and the appropriate attributes to refer the favicon

Comment: @MaxDesiatov Now, when you call `.head` from any function in your HTMLFactory should call head from your custom Node extension instead of calling head from PlotComponents.